# Who stopped the bullet in the first X-Men movie?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-2000

When Rogue ran away to the train station and

> Magneto was abducting her to use her for his machine

Magneto, Toad and Sabertooth ran into Jean Grey and Prof X outside the station. Magneto then grabs all of the guns from many policemen's hands and aimed them back at the officers. After some dialogue, Magneto fires one of the guns, but the bullet is stopped before hitting someone's head. The scene then cuts to Jean Grey looking at the bullet as if she had something to do with stopping it, but Magneto mentions that he can't stop all the bullets.

So did Jean Grey stop the bullet or did Magneto? The bullet was still being driven into the officer's head, which suggests that Magneto was controlling it as it wouldn't be moving forward anymore if it was stopped. But why would there be so much emphasis on Jean during that scene if she didn't have anything to do with stopping the bullet?

Comment: I've always wondered, if he was able to control Sabertooth and Toad, why not use them to remove Magneto's helmet instead of going for the throat? That way he could then take over Magneto...

Comment: @sunpech, the same thing occurred to me. I concluded that 1) Magneto could pull the triggers (or just release the hammers) quicker than Sabertooth could possibly get the helmet off, and 2) trying to "take the reins" from Magneto in a situation like that would have been far from safe.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Magneto stopped the bullet.

The scene already had Magneto controlling the guns, locked and loaded to fire at the police before Xavier controlled Sabertooth and Toad. He basically had them as hostages during their conversation.

[image: Magneto controls the guns to point to the police holding them.]

He fires the bullet and stops it with some effort. Now if he were to fire all the guns, it would take a lot of effort to stop each bullet, which he claims he may not be able to control. So he puts it to Charles: *either kill me and also risk the lives of the policemen with guns pointed to them, or let me go* (paraphrased).

[image: A spinning bullet, stopped by Magneto]

There was some emphasis with Jean next to Charles Xavier, with the back and forth scenes, to highlight that Charles had a difficult decision to make, with someone there to witness it, his star pupil. Either Xavier kills Magneto in cold blood and risk the lives of the policemen there, but *ending* the evil plot Magneto was planning and rescue Rogue... or let him go and fight another time.

Also, I don't believe Jean had enough control with telekinesis to stop a bullet either. *At least not yet.*

[image: Jean Grey sitting next to Xavier]

Comment: He also makes the comment, "I don't think I can stop them all", referring to the guns he just has cocked and aimed at the other policemen.

Comment: For the life of me, I can't find the script online, but doesn't he say "**You** can't stop them all, Charles."? (Emphasis mine)

Comment: @Quintis555 *"Care to press your luck, Charles? I don't think I can stop them all."* - Magneto source: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120903/quotes

Comment: It is possible that he could have actually stopped them all, but was simply bluffing. After all, if he was able to lift the entire Golden Gate bridge and float it down to Alcatraz, then stopping those bullets shouldnot have been that hard. Granted the bullets are far smaller, and he was lifting the bridge With Jean helping him somewhat too. He could have just been saying that to get Charles to let him Go. But either way, we know Charles was not about to take that chance.

Comment: @JediWitness That would require X-Men 3 to exist. Which it doesn't, so that never happened.

Comment: @Django - Yup I know, but Magneto still had the same power. I was just using the Golden Gate as an example. He already said he could stop bullets in X-men First Class and he did turn the radio telescope and lift that submarine, so we know he could have done it easily.

Comment: Magneto was still controlling the bullet and the threat to the man was still real Magneto could have used his powers to let the bullet go at the same rate as if it was fired. He did just that with the steel balls when he escaped from his plastic prison killing the guards. Xavier would have known that since he moved the coin through Shaws head slowly killing him, so he surely could have done the same thing with the bullet. That's why Magneto said to Charles after Charles let Toad go "Still unwilling to make sacrifices.. that's what makes you weak", showing that Magneto could have well done it.

Comment: The problem I have with that whole sequence is the understanding of magnetism itself. Magneto controls magnetic forces but bullets are made of non-magnetic material (lead and copper). They're non-ferrous and no more magnetic than plastic darts.

Comment: @Morgan - Magneto's power (in the movies at least) is to control metals, not magnetic fields. His name is somewhat confusing, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

The scene cut has screwed things up. When Magneto pointed guns on police, Xavier trapped the neck of Magneto using Sabertooth. Magneto understood that it's Xavier. He told hidden Xavier to retreat, but Xavier didn't listen. So, he displayed a demo. He fired a bullet and slowed down.

Comment: Your last paragraph makes no sense... What do you mean?

Comment: @Oghma Oh sorry, I mixed that from another movie.. removed.

Answer (score 1):

It was Magneto, the film's cutting is poor.  Essentially it is a show of force to Xavier.  Magneto showed he was capable of firing the guns but he did not want to kill the officer yet as that removed a bargaining chip.  Also, if he began killing people Xavier might make a snap decision to protect them and kill Magneto.

Comment: Could the divebomber leave a comment so I know what I might need to improve here?