# Was Magneto pushing the bullet into the police officer's head?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, magneto

As has been pointed out. Magneto did have the ability to stop the bullet fired at the officer in X Men II. Here's the rub... bullets aren't rockets with motors. Once their forward motion caused by the expansion of burning gunpowder is stopped, they stop. The bullet is obviously still being pushing forward into the officer's forehead after forward motion has been stopped, propelled by some force. The gunpowder has been spent and is no longer a factor as a propellant. That force then must be Magneto, unless I'm missing something.

Note: this question is not about who fired the gun or who initially STOPPED the bullet from hitting the cop. It's about the bullet staying at the officer's head and apparently boring forward AFTER its been stopped. Is Magneto trying to push it forward and Jean trying to stop it?

Physics dictates that once the forward momentum of the bullet is stopped, it should just fall to the ground unless it's being HELD in place.

Comment: Some people can't keep time stops and telekinesis straight....

Comment: Sounds like you've answered your own question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Magneto can't do time stops. He is good controlling metal though.

Comment: "*bullets aren't rockets with motors. Once their forward motion caused by the expansion of burning gunpowder is stopped, they stop.*" You may wish to check out Newton's First Law.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I meant forward momentum of the projectile. An object in motion... an object at rest and all that...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who stopped the bullet in the first X-Men movie?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18880/who-stopped-the-bullet-in-the-first-x-men-movie)

Comment: So I can safely assume there is nothing going on there other than bad writing. Going for the sight gag trope?

Comment: @Richard Just looked at that question and answers. Not the same question and the answers don't pertain to this question. This question goes a step or two further.

Comment: @Morgan - It basically confirms that Magneto was controlling the bullet. That answers the question asked, albeit perhaps not to your satisfaction.

Comment: @Richard He could have pulled the guys belt buckle off and did the same thing then. The way they made it look in the movie is that Magneto was "holding the bullet back" from continuing on its destructive path. I was wondering why the cop didn't just step back from the suspended bullet and if Jean and Magneto were having a power struggle.

Comment: @Richard I think the suggested dupe actually claims that Magneto (claims he) wouldn't be able to stop *all the other bullets* if he fired the rest of the guns. It doesn't actually answer whether there is some momentum magically stored in the currently frozen bullet, though. The movie makes it look as if he was "restraining" the bullet from hitting the cop, which would be absurd even for a fantasy movie. Or maybe I misunderstood the issue? :P

Comment: @AndresF. No, you aren't missing the point of this question.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, Magneto was controlling the bullet.

> Magneto laughed throatily. **He had fired at point-blank range into the
> face of one cop, then had stopped the bullet just as it touched the
> man’s skin.** The bullet was still hanging there, the heat from it
> burning the man’s forehead. The cop’s eyes were huge, and Magneto had
> no doubt the poor fool had wet his pants from the fear.
>
> <sub><sup>[X-Men: A Novel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0345440951)</sup></sub>

Comment: So that also means that Prof X was just as ignorant of basic physics and got played?

Comment: @Morgan - The threat is still there. Magneto could (if he so chose) push that bullet through the policeman's head with no effort whatsoever.

Comment: Also it would be very hot, it would not be comfortable to have that touching your face after it was just fired from a gun.

Comment: @Probst I don't think I would just stand there and grunt as a hot stationary oblect was in contact with my forehead.

Comment: To me, the question here is what would require Magneto to exert an *additional* force. Suppose Magneto is distracted and he stops exerting his superpowered influence on the bullet: does the movie expect us to believe that: a- the bullet falls to the ground, since it's currently stationary, or b- the bullet regains momentum and flies through the cop's head, just as if Magneto had hit play after pausing the movie? If the option is (a), then there is no risk if the X-Men distract Magneto, but I think the movie is going for (b).

Comment: @AndresF. - If Magneto loses interest, the bullet will simply drop to the ground.

Comment: @AndresF. If you watch *X-Men: First Class*, you can see the effects of Magneto repeatedly being distracted and re-attaining focus on what he's trying to do.

Comment: If Magneto was strong enough to remove all the bullet's momentum in a fraction of a second, he must have been strong enough to impart the same amount of momentum to the bullet in a similarly short time.  To be sure of saving the cop, Xavier would have to render Magneto unconscious in less time that it took to push the bullet forward - which he is unlikely to be able to do.  The fact Magneto was fast enough to "grab" the bullet between the gun muzzles and the cop's head suggests he'll have no trouble dispatching the cop if he starts to move.